# Why did the Soviets refuse to help Nur Mohammed Taraki?

Tags: united-states, soviet-union, civil-war, afghanistan

In 1970s Afghanistan was a communist state. The leader [Nur Mohammed Taraki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nur_Muhammad_Taraki) was much like a puppet of the Soviets. When the policies (education, land distribution etc.) initiated by the Soviets proved to be unsuccessful, the Mujahideens (Islamic Soldiers) fought with the Afghan army which is what we know as The Soviet War.

Now...my question is that Afghanistan was surrounded by Iran and could be a better way to reach the Persian Gulf and also the discovery of oil in 20th century was a major source of "lust" to the Super Powers especially Soviets and the US then why the Soviet Leader refused to help Afghan Allies in the war against the Mujahideens? Why did the Soviets let such an important state go?

Was it a part of strategy? Was the US intervention irritating them and making them feared?

Or they were just enjoying the barbaric show...the very famous policy prevalent nowadays "let them fight and die...we'll just enjoy the show and when the right time  will come we will grab the opportunity and then will become heros of the nation"??

Comment: Perhaps it was that the cost (it was a vast military operation) was becoming prohibitive, at a time when the USSR was approaching the point of economic collapse.

Comment: This reads more like politics than history -"barbaric show"  "famous policy", etc.  These are not neutral words; the create the impression that you're looking for arguments, not answers.

Answer (score 2):

> why the Soviet Leader refused to help Afghan Allies in the war against the Mujahideens?

Well, they didn't refuse to provide any help except "foot on the ground". And the reasons they had are obvious if we remember what actually happened.

One may argue that the level of support came out to be unsufficient etc. Well, errare humanum est. Probably they hoped too long that Taraki would sort it out himself.

After all, as we know, Andropov and Ustinov insisted on direct intervention in December 1979. Though even then it was split decision. There's also a widespread opinion that Brezhnev finally agreed on the military operation because of personal matters (he considered Taraki a good friend and was very upset after his murder, so he particularly disliked the idea to cooperate with Amin anymore).

Comment: This answer would be improved with sources.